# Append values to several cells in cell array

Tags: matlab

Imagine I have a cell array

```
A = {0, 1 ,2, 3, ...}
```

and indice vector

```
I = [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, ...]
```

and values

```
V = [2, 3]
```

and I want something like

```
A{I} = [A{I}; V]' = {0, [1 2], 2, [3 3], ....};
```

That is, I want to append several values to some cells of a cell array at once. How would I do that most elegantly/efficiently? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `cellfun`

```
A(I==1) = cellfun( @(x,y) [x y], A(I==1), num2cell(V), 'UniformOutput', 0 );
```

Note the usage of regular subscripting (using `()`, rather than `{}`) to index the chosen cell elements using `I==1`. Also note that `V` is passed as a cell array (using `num2cell`) and not as a regular array.